# Using Python eval to evaluate classes

Tags: python, oop, eval, kivy

How I can use eval to made class definitions inside other class ?

```
evalstr = str("class MyScreen(Screen):\n\tpass\n")
eval(evalstr)
```

I want to execute this code in other class method. But it returns an error.

Comment: Please update the question with the error you are getting and the code which generates the error (i.e. the context for the code above).

Comment: You can use `type` to dynamically create types, if that is the core of the problem.

Comment: Why are you doing this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `exec` not `eval` here (security concerns aside)

```
evalstr = str("class MyScreen(Screen):\n\tpass\n")
exec(evalstr)
```

`eval` will only evaluate an expression and return it's value.  `exec` is used for executing arbitrary code strings as statements, which is what you need here.

But seriously this is a security disaster waiting to happen in most cases, consider alternatives (like writing the code not as a string).

EDIT:
Chepner's answer is probably the right way to go.

Comment: Certainly, it's easy to abuse `exec`, and in most cases (like this one) there are better ways to achieve the desired result. But use of `exec` shouldn't be a security concern if you can **guarantee** that its argument is [sane](http://xkcd.com/327/). Or is it? Of course, most people who casually use `exec` don't (or can't) ensure that the code they're `exec`ing _is_ properly sanitized...

Comment: @PM2Ring using `exec` or `eval` in this case suggests to me that the string wouldn't be known prior to run time.  However, looking at the question closer it seems OP didn't realize you could have nested classes.  You're right that if the code is sanitized it's safe of course.

Comment: I agree that this case suggests that the string wouldn't be known prior to run time. And I think we both agree that it's generally easier to avoid using `exec` or `eval` in the first place than to properly sanitize such strings, especially if they depend heavily on user input. I was just mentioning that while use of `exec` or `eval` can be risky they aren't intrinsically risky.

Comment: FWIW, when I was a new Python programmer, I used `exec` to build some multiply-nested for loops where the depth of nesting was only known at run-time. And I didn't want to (or couldn't figure out how to) use recursion. Maybe I should look at that old code & see if I can refactor it. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `type` function instead:

```
MyScreen = type("MyScreen", (Screen,), {})
```

This is the correct way to create a class at run-time (and in fact is essentially what executing a `class` statement does, since `type` is also the default metaclass in Python).

You can also simply define the class the "normal" way; there's nothing that says a `class` statement must be at the global level of a module:

```
class Something(object):

    # Define a new class here...
    class MyScreen(Screen):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a Something object"""
        # ... or here
        class MyScreen(Screen):
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `eval` for that because `class` is a statement, and `eval` only evaluates expressions, not statements.  You could use `exec`.